# Change Cursor to Square when Combobox text is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have Editable Combobox in WPF,way it should work is, if text is selected(highlighted), cursor should turn into cross so user can know he can move text into another Combobox, and if user try yo edit cursor should be edit cursor.

Here is code I am trying right now, onFocus Event,

```
   private void LocationComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)sender;
        var edit = (TextBox)combo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combo);

       var selectedText = edit.SelectedText;

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedText))
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
}
```

here is screen shot

[image]

As in Snap, since Austin,TX is highlighted, my cursor should be cross!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
private void cmb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TxtBox = (TextBox)cmb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cmb);
        if (TxtBox != null)
        {
            TxtBox.SelectionChanged += TxtBox_SelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    void TxtBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var TxtBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (TxtBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtBox.SelectedText))
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }
        else
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
    }
```